# application defined or object defined error when trying to pass an array

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I am trying to pass an array to the pivot table fields, but on doing so excel throws a run time error:1004 error "Application defined or object defined error". Below is the piece of code I have written in VBA:

```
Sub ARRAYER()
    Dim i As Double
    Dim ALM(8) As String

    Sheet15.PivotTables("significance_pivot2").PivotFields("Pagename"). _
    ClearAllFilters
    For i = 1 To 8
        ALM(i) = CStr(Sheet4.Range("F" + CStr(i + 2) + "").Text)
    Next

    For i = 1 To 8
        Sheet4.Range("AA" & i).Value = ALM(i)
    Next i

    Sheet15.PivotTables("significance_pivot2").PivotFields("Pagename").VisibleItemsList = Array(ALM)-- It trows an error here!!!

End Sub
```

Comment: is it an OLAP Pivot table ? See [MSDN: PivotField.VisibleItemsList Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb242470(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try an alternative like this:

```
Sub ARRAYER()
Dim i As Double
Dim ALM() As String '  dimensioned automatically by VBA on assignment from Range

Sheet15.PivotTables("significance_pivot2").PivotFields("Pagename"). _
ClearAllFilters

ALM = CStr(Sheet4.Range("F3:F11".value)

' maybe just copy the source data directly?
range("F3:F11").copy destination:= range("AA3")

Sheet15.PivotTables("significance_pivot2").PivotFields("Pagename").VisibleItemsList = Array(ALM())-- Changed to add brackets

End Sub
```